# Can't access mdf file in desktop application

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I need your help.. maybe it's the small task which I am not able to solve but I don't know how to search that on any search engine

I am using an `.mdf` file (vs 2103) in my WPF login register desktop application.. Everything is working fine, no compilation errors. I inserted some data into the `.mdf` file by using query in Visual Studio and then try to login through application and it's working fine. Moreover I am also able to register, i.e., insert into `.mdf` file from the register option of application if I use the "absolute path" of the `.mdf` file. Problem begins when I try to insert into `.mdf` file using a "relative path"... it doesn't insert data into the `.mdf`....I don't know why.

(this absolute path is not working. I have `.mdf` file in the database folder)

```
//connection string 
connetionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
 
//code
SqlCommand sqlCmd;
string sql = null;
SqlConnection sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

try
{
    sqlCnn.Open();
    sql = "insert into [NewTable] ( Name , Password  )  values ('ABC' , '12345')";

    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn);
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCnn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("You have Been Registered");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
}
```

It shows the message "You have Been Registered"

but is not visible in .mdf file...
I want to ask..why is it behaving like this....and I want to use the relative path as we cant judge the client system absolute path...what mistake I am doing? how to handle this (i guess self made) issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole *AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `MyDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand excellent blog article [Bad habits to kick: Using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more in depth explanations and tips

Comment: Thanks for you quick response....Every thing is working perfectly if i am using ssms but why not with .mdf....I dont want to install ssms on the client system so i this i must have to use .mdf file (may b i have any misconception correct me if i am wrong)...

As you said "you're just looking at the wrong .mdf file in the end! "...then which Mdf i have to look for? bin\debug\\Database\Database1.mdf ??

Comment: @Mrspider94: yes, if you use *relative paths* in your `AttachDbFileName=`, then Visual Studio will be copying around the `.mdf` file - that's a real mess and a source of lots of confusion and grief that you can *spare yourself* if you put the database **on the server** where it belongs in the first plcae

Comment: Opes Sad to hear :(
What to do if i don't want to install sql server express on my client machine...any substitue for holding the data for limited amount of time...and then update it to the remote sql server because i dont want to insert data in realtime on remote sql server (Considering network issues) I have a lot of confusion related to inventory management system...If you allow me i would like to get few more sugestions

Comment: @Mrspider94: if you want to use `.mdf`, you ***MUST*** install SQL Server Express - you ***CANNOT*** use `.mdf` ***without*** at least SQL Server Express.

Comment: Okay got you but  still confused what to do...What to use if i don't want my customers to additionally install any software...For simplicity assume the small scenario...what should i use if i want to develop the application which takes multiple registrations and the record of that user where i have to save that data in my application...i hope forcing user to install sql server is not a good practice so what should i use for that application so that user have to just install my app nothing else....it may b dumb question but i cant search this on google or may b i dont know how to search :/